# CentOS doesn't see USB device

Tags: centos, virtualbox, usb-drive, fdisk

I'm running CentOS 6.3 inside of VirtualBox and am having trouble seeing my USB 2.0 thumb drive.
In VirtualBox I go to Devices, USB drives and can capture my connected thumb drive.  I've created a mount point in CentOS but fdisk doesn't show the drive (I'm expecting to see SDC) there.
What am I missing?

Comment: What is your host OS? Can you see an event pertaining to the device in Centos' **dmesg** output (open a shell, plug the device in, then type **dmesg** followed by enter)?

Comment: What is the filesystem on your thumb drive? If it is NTFS, for instance, CentOS as shipped won't read it (needs ntfs-3g from EPEL).

Comment: Oh, and what do you see in `/media/` after capturing?

Answer (score 3):

An USB thumb drive should show up in `sysfs` under `/sys/block/` and should be named `sd*`. Here is a short script which checks every device under `/sys/block` if it is an USB drive:

```
#!/bin/bash

function is_usb_disk()
{
        device=$1
        is_usb_attached=$(udevadm info --query=property --path="/sys/block/$device" | grep -i "^ID_BUS=usb$")
        is_disk=$(udevadm info --query=property --path="/sys/block/$device" | grep -i "^ID_TYPE=disk$")
        if [[ -n $is_usb_attached && -n $is_disk ]]; then
                return 0
        else
                return 1
        fi
}

for block_device in $(ls /sys/block); do
        is_usb_disk $block_device
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
                serial=$(udevadm info --query=property --path="/sys/block/$block_device" | grep "^ID_SERIAL=" | cut -d "=" -f 2)
                echo "/dev/$block_device ($serial) is an USB disk."
        fi
done
```

This script checks for every block device if it is attached to the USB bus (via property ID_BUS) and if it is a disk (via property ID_TYPE). If it finds a device there both is true it prints the device node with the corresponding device serial.

You can just copy that to a file e.g. `find_usb_disks.sh`. 
Give it execute permission via `chmod u+x find_usb_disks.sh` and run it. The output will look like that:

```
/dev/sdb (0204_Flash_Disk_19250701EF6B1E05-0:0) is an USB disk.
```

If it doesn't return anything, it is likely that your thumb drive isn't "inserted" properly. Check via `lsmod` if modules like `usb_storage` are loaded. If usb_storage is not loaded, unplug your device, run

```
modprobe usb_storage
```

plug it in again and see if your thumb drive appears. A good way to monitor if your device is recognized by the kernel is

```
udevadm monitor
```

Unplug your USB device, run that command, plug your device in again. As soon as you plug your usb device in, you should see kernel (and udev) "add" actions.

Remember that if the disk has partitions a partition number will be attached to the device node name (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`). My script wouldn't find the partition, it just checks if a devices was added properly.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install Extension pack for this . read this
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing